# Proving a linearity of a homogeneous differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

Let $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ satisfy a linear homogeneous differential equation $Lu=f$ where $f$ is a function of an independent variable. Show that the linear combination $c_{1}u_{1}+c_{2}u_{2}$ fails to satisfy that equation when $c_{1}+c_{2}\neq 1$

What i tried

The linearity formula is $$L(c_{1}u_{1}+c_{2}u_{2})=c_{1}L(u_{1})+c_{2}L(u_{2})$$

where $L$ is a differential operator.

Proving by contradiction

suppose that the linear combination $c_{1}u_{1}+c_{2}u_{2}$  satisfy that equation when $c_{1}+c_{2}= 1$

I let $$c_{2}= 1-c_{1}$$ then i substituting this into the LHS of the lineearity formuala to get rid of the $c_{2}$ term. Thus i got

$$L(c_{1}u_{1}+c_{2}u_{2})=L(c_{1}u_{1}+(1-c_{1})u_{2})=L(c_{1}u_{1}+u_{2}-c_{1}u_{2})$$

then

$$L(c_{1}u_{1}+u_{2}-c_{1}u_{2})=c_{1}L(u_{1})-c_{1}L(u_{2})+L(u_{2})$$

Where
$$L(u_{2})=0$$ due to the property of the linear homogeneous equation

Then we can clearly see that

$$c_{1}L(u_{1})-c_{1}L(u_{2})$$ clearly does not equal to the RHS of the linearity formula thus a contradiction and thus proving the original statement. Is my proof correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: You are not proving what was asked, which is to show that when $c_1+c_2 \ne 1$ the sum does not satisfy the original equation. Why are you assuming that $c_1+c_2 = 1$, the opposite of what is stated? Also, why are you assuming $L(u_2) = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
L(c_1u_1+c_2u_2)&=c_1L(u_1)+c_2L(u_2)\\\\
&=c_1f+c_2f\\\\
&=(c_1+c_2)f\\\\
&\ne f
\end{align}$$

unless $c_1+c_2=1$.

Comment: I meant that sign $\ne =0$?

Comment: I've edited the typographical error.